# Плавный поворот изображения на заданный угол

Tags: java, разработка-игр, swing

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как картинку формата PNG **плавно** поворачивать на заданный угол в Swing?

*Обновление*

Проблема в том, что я могу повернуть изображение на заданный угол путём мгновенной перерисовки от исходного положения картинки (да можно даже не картинки, а прямоугольника, например) до заданного, а мне нужно, чтобы плавно он перерисовывался, не сразу, вот.

Comment: Может и код приведёте перерисовки? Это упростит)